# nested iterator, 2 iterations in one model, collect values, cell statistics, batch processing dialogue box

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, batch, iterator

(ArcGIS10, SP2, ArcInfo)

This is my model, and it works perfectly, but...

[image: model]

I do have a large amount of data to process. The interim output files (from raster calculator, collect value) would reach the capacity of my hard drive. Therefore, I cut my input shape file into tiles and want to run it on all tiles and just overwrite the interim output files which are create for each feature.

However, as we all know, the model builder does not allow using two iterators in one model.

I used to do this with the batch processing function (http://www.lib.uoguelph.ca/resources..._arcgis_10.pdf).

However, the cell statistics tool does not allow me edit the output location within the batch dialogue box (after right clicking on the model, batch).

[image: batch dialogue box]

The fields are greyed in the table and I cannot add further output locations. Thus, I cannot run the model on several input files.

I guess it is a buck of the combination of cell statistics and collect values. Only the combination of those two tools resulted in this problem.

Potential solution for my problem are:

**• Fixing the problem with the output location within the batch dialogue box.**

**• Substituting the combination of cell statistics and collect values by anything else resulting in the same outcome.**

**• Using any other possible way to run a feature iterator on several feature classes (something like a nested iterator)**

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've only looked quickly at it but are you able to get your second iterator into a sub-model?

Answer (score 4):

Two iterators are allowed within a model *as long as you embed a model within a model*.  Check out the **advanced use of model iterators** section on the [integrating a model within a model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007p000000) help page.